# Is it possible to assign a new ListNode to an already existing node of a linkedlist?

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that inputs the linked list associated with `head2` after  the occurrence of the variable location in the list associated with `head1`. However, I keep getting a core dump:

```
void mergeLists(ListNode *head1, ListNode *head2, const int &location){
  ListNode *tail1, *tail2, *run;
  tail1=head1;
  tail2=head2;
  if(head1->pointer_Next!=nullptr){
    while(tail1->content!=location){
      tail1=tail1->pointer_Next;
    }
    if(head2->pointer_Next!=nullptr){
      while(tail2->pointer_Next!=nullptr){
        run=tail1->pointer_Next;
        tail1->pointer_Next=new ListNode;
        tail1=tail1->pointer_Next;
        tail1->content=tail2->content;
        tail1->pointer_Next=run;
        tail2=tail2->pointer_Next;
      } 
    }
  }
  delete tail1;
  delete tail2;
  delete run;
}
```

Is there something illegal about the operation in line 12? I ran this through GDB and I am pretty sure that this is where the problem is. I have tried setting pointer to next to `nullptr` but it produces the same result. Does anyone have an idea where the core dump is occurring?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues about your code, which i can see even without debugging. Please post test case + error + ListNode definition.

```
void mergeLists(ListNode *head1, ListNode *head2, const int &location){
  ListNode *tail1, *tail2, *run;
  tail1=head1;
  tail2=head2;
  if(head1->pointer_Next!=nullptr){ <------ What if head1 is nullptr ?
    while(tail1->content!=location){  <---- What if tail1 is nullptr ?
      tail1=tail1->pointer_Next;      <---- What if tail1->pointer_Next is nullptr ?
    }
    if(head2->pointer_Next!=nullptr){  <--- What if head2 is nullptr ?
      while(tail2->pointer_Next!=nullptr){ <--- What if tail2 is nullptr ?
        run=tail1->pointer_Next;
        tail1->pointer_Next=new ListNode;
        tail1=tail1->pointer_Next;
        tail1->content=tail2->content;
        tail1->pointer_Next=run;
        tail2=tail2->pointer_Next;
      } 
    }
  }
  delete tail1; <---- Why do you delete tail1 , which is Node in the list
  delete tail2; <---- Why do you delete tail2 , which is Node in the list
  delete run;
}
```